# Work around Keras TypeError limitation when calling layer "tf.keras.backend.rnn_1"

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, lstm

I am trying to use Keras for an attention mechanism in a machine translation using an LSTM network.

However, I get a TypeError exception when in my code.

```
TypeError: Exception encountered when calling layer "tf.keras.backend.rnn_1" (type TFOpLambda).

You are passing KerasTensor(type_spec=TensorSpec(shape=(None, 35), dtype=tf.float32, name=None), name='tf.compat.v1.nn.softmax_3/Softmax:0', description="created by layer 'tf.compat.v1.nn.softmax_3'"), an intermediate Keras symbolic input/output, to a TF API that does not allow registering custom dispatchers, such as `tf.cond`, `tf.function`, gradient tapes, or `tf.map_fn`. Keras Functional model construction only supports TF API calls that *do* support dispatching, such as `tf.math.add` or `tf.reshape`. Other APIs cannot be called directly on symbolic Kerasinputs/outputs. You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer `call` and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.
```

It seems `You can work around this limitation by putting the operation in a custom Keras layer call and calling that layer on this symbolic input/output.` Does anyone know what this means?

The main code is here and it fails at `attention_result, attention_weights = attention_layer([encoder_outputs1, decoder_outputs])`

```
# Encoder 

encoder_inputs = Input(shape=(max_length_english,)) 
enc_emb = Embedding(vocab_size_source, 1024,trainable=True)(encoder_inputs) 

# Bidirectional lstm layer
enc_lstm1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(256,return_sequences=True,return_state=True))
encoder_outputs1, forw_state_h, forw_state_c, back_state_h, back_state_c = enc_lstm1(enc_emb)

final_enc_h = Concatenate()([forw_state_h,back_state_h])
final_enc_c = Concatenate()([forw_state_c,back_state_c])

encoder_states =[final_enc_h, final_enc_c]

# Set up the decoder. 
decoder_inputs = Input(shape=(None,)) 
dec_emb_layer = Embedding(vocab_size_target, 1024,trainable=True) 
dec_emb = dec_emb_layer(decoder_inputs)

#LSTM using encoder_states as initial state
decoder_lstm = LSTM(512, return_sequences=True, return_state=True) 
decoder_outputs, _, _ = decoder_lstm(dec_emb, initial_state=encoder_states)

#Attention Layer
attention_layer = AttentionLayer()
attention_result, attention_weights = attention_layer([encoder_outputs1, decoder_outputs])

# Concat attention output and decoder LSTM output 
decoder_concat_input = Concatenate(axis=-1, name='concat_layer')([decoder_outputs, attention_result])

#Dense layer
decoder_dense = Dense(vocab_size_target, activation='softmax')
decoder_outputs = decoder_dense(decoder_concat_input)


# Define the model
model = Model([encoder_inputs, decoder_inputs], decoder_outputs)
```

The relevant code for attention.py is

```
def call(self, inputs, verbose=False):
        """
        inputs: [encoder_output_sequence, decoder_output_sequence]
        """
        assert type(inputs) == list
        encoder_out_seq, decoder_out_seq = inputs
        if verbose:
            print('encoder_out_seq>', encoder_out_seq.shape)
            print('decoder_out_seq>', decoder_out_seq.shape)

        def energy_step(inputs, states):
            """ Step function for computing energy for a single decoder state """

            assert_msg = "States must be a list. However states {} is of type {}".format(states, type(states))
            assert isinstance(states, list) or isinstance(states, tuple), assert_msg

            """ Some parameters required for shaping tensors"""
            en_seq_len, en_hidden = encoder_out_seq.shape[1], encoder_out_seq.shape[2]
            de_hidden = inputs.shape[-1]

            """ Computing S.Wa where S=[s0, s1, ..., si]"""
            # <= batch_size*en_seq_len, latent_dim
            reshaped_enc_outputs = K.reshape(encoder_out_seq, (-1, en_hidden))
            # <= batch_size*en_seq_len, latent_dim
            W_a_dot_s = K.reshape(K.dot(reshaped_enc_outputs, self.W_a), (-1, en_seq_len, en_hidden))
            if verbose:
                print('wa.s>',W_a_dot_s.shape)

            """ Computing hj.Ua """
            U_a_dot_h = K.expand_dims(K.dot(inputs, self.U_a), 1)  # <= batch_size, 1, latent_dim
            if verbose:
                print('Ua.h>',U_a_dot_h.shape)

            """ tanh(S.Wa + hj.Ua) """
            # <= batch_size*en_seq_len, latent_dim
            reshaped_Ws_plus_Uh = K.tanh(K.reshape(W_a_dot_s + U_a_dot_h, (-1, en_hidden)))
            if verbose:
                print('Ws+Uh>', reshaped_Ws_plus_Uh.shape)

            """ softmax(va.tanh(S.Wa + hj.Ua)) """
            # <= batch_size, en_seq_len
            e_i = K.reshape(K.dot(reshaped_Ws_plus_Uh, self.V_a), (-1, en_seq_len))
            # <= batch_size, en_seq_len
            e_i = K.softmax(e_i)

            if verbose:
                print('ei>', e_i.shape)

            return e_i, [e_i]

        def context_step(inputs, states):
            """ Step function for computing ci using ei """
            # <= batch_size, hidden_size
            c_i = K.sum(encoder_out_seq * K.expand_dims(inputs, -1), axis=1)
            if verbose:
                print('ci>', c_i.shape)
            return c_i, [c_i]

        def create_inital_state(inputs, hidden_size):
            # We are not using initial states, but need to pass something to K.rnn funciton
            fake_state = K.zeros_like(inputs)  # <= (batch_size, enc_seq_len, latent_dim
            fake_state = K.sum(fake_state, axis=[1, 2])  # <= (batch_size)
            fake_state = K.expand_dims(fake_state)  # <= (batch_size, 1)
            fake_state = K.tile(fake_state, [1, hidden_size])  # <= (batch_size, latent_dim
            return fake_state

        fake_state_c = create_inital_state(encoder_out_seq, encoder_out_seq.shape[-1])
        fake_state_e = create_inital_state(encoder_out_seq, encoder_out_seq.shape[1])  # <= (batch_size, enc_seq_len, latent_dim

        """ Computing energy outputs """
        # e_outputs => (batch_size, de_seq_len, en_seq_len)
        last_out, e_outputs, _ = K.rnn(
            energy_step, decoder_out_seq, [fake_state_e],
        )

        """ Computing context vectors """
        last_out, c_outputs, _ = K.rnn(
            context_step, e_outputs, [fake_state_c],
        )

        return c_outputs, e_outputs
```

and it fails at

```
""" Computing energy outputs """
        # e_outputs => (batch_size, de_seq_len, en_seq_len)
        last_out, e_outputs, _ = K.rnn(
            energy_step, decoder_out_seq, [fake_state_e],
        )
```

If anyone knows how to fix this and work around this limitation, please advise. Thank you so much.

Comment: facing the same issue. I am surprised that no one has even commented on this question yet.

Comment: Same issue. Someone please help

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you are using the Attention Layer provided in this repo : https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras/blob/master/src/layers/attention.py

If so, it is evident if you check in the issues section that the author has been unable to resolve the issue : https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras/issues/59

I was facing a similar issue for a while and then I decided to shift to the Attention Layers provided by the Keras.

If you are looking for Additive Attention, Bahdanau-style, change your attention layer code to this :

```
#call attention using:
from tensorflow.keras.layers import AdditiveAttention
 
#Modify your code and provide decoder_outputs first and encoder_outputs next as parameters.
attention_result = AdditiveAttention(use_scale=True)([decoder_outputs, encoder_outputs1])
```

for any additional help check the documentation here: https://keras.io/api/layers/attention_layers/additive_attention/

If you want to use any other attention variant you can also check from the other options provided by Keras here:
https://keras.io/api/layers/attention_layers/

Comment: is this is a good alternative to solve the problem. because i found out that the number of parameter changed when using this alternative. Regards.

Answer (score 0):

There is a workaround that I found when using the attention layer provided in the example repo :
https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras/blob/master/src/layers/attention.py

The way I found is to remove the python Keras backend module you have imported as K as the example below.

Import before:

```py
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
```

Import after:

```py
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
```

This seems to fix the issue of compatibility when using Tensorflow > 2.5 versions with the Attention Layer used in the repo.

It might be best to replace other `tensorflow.python.keras` dependencies in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use this:

```
from tensorflow.keras.layers import Layer 
from tensorflow.keras import backend as K
```

instead of:

```
from tensorflow.python.keras.layers import Layer  
from tensorflow.python.keras import backend as K
```

during model building in the previous step, this worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

I have encountered the same issue ([Github Issue](https://github.com/thushv89/attention_keras/issues/59)), with the `Attention Layer`
I have used [AdditiveAttention](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/AdditiveAttention) Layer to solve this.